# UnicodeDecodeError when concatenating strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-unicode

I've got the following little Python 2.7 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import geoip2.database

def ret_country_iso(ip):
    reader = geoip2.database.Reader('/usr/local/geoip/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
    response = reader.country(ip)
    return response.country.iso_code.lower()

result = ret_country_iso("8.8.8.8")
print result
result += "Роман"
print result
```

where, as you can see, I first figure out the country where the "8.8.8.8" IP is located (this returns "us" - see below) and then I concatenate a short string to it which contains some Russian characters.

Result:

```
# ./script.py
us
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./script.py", line 12, in <module>
    result += "Роман"
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now, if I try the following instead

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

result = "us"
print result
result += "Роман"
print result
```

Then everything's ok:

```
./script.py 
us
usРоман
```

Obviously then, the 'ret_country_iso()' function returns something different than the literal "us" string, my Python is too poor though to say.

How to correct the above?

EDIT: following the advice of snakecharmerb, the following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import geoip2.database

def ret_country_iso(ip):
    reader = geoip2.database.Reader('/usr/local/geoip/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
    response = reader.country(ip)
    return response.country.iso_code.lower().encode('utf-8')

result = ret_country_iso("8.8.8.8")
print result
result += "Роман"
print result
```

Comment: `result` might be a `unicode` object; does `result += u"Роман"` work?

Comment: sadly no, but it does change the error I get to "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters..."

Comment: Is that on the `result +=` line or the second `print result` line?

Comment: yes, you're right - now the error is on the second 'print' - didn't notice that...

Comment: So that tells us that (1) `result` is a unicode object, so you can only concatenate it with other unicode objects (2) Your terminal (or whereever your `print` output goes) isn't configured to handle unicode.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Last question: now I've tried unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', result).encode('ascii', 'ignore') to convert the unicode object ot a python String - and only then result += "Роман" but still the same error...

Comment: You probably want `str_result = result.encode('utf-8')` (you can use other encodings, but they must be able to handle cyrillic characters)

Comment: oh yes, now it's fully working. Thanks a lot from a Python noob. If you want to write an official answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 does not strictly distinguish between unicode and bytes, so the results of concatenating the two types are inconsistent:

```py
u'abc' + 'def'
```

succeeds, but

```py
u'US' + 'Роман'
```

results in an exception.  The usual approach - the "Unicode Sandwich" pattern - is to decode and encode string-type data at the edges of an application, and work only with unicode within the application (for applications which deal primarily with bytes the reverse pattern is adopted).

So, when combining `str` and `unicode` instances you can take either of these options:

```py
# unicode result
u'US ' + 'Роман'.decode('utf-8')

# str result
u'US '.encode('utf-8') + 'Роман'
```

but the key is to be consistent throughout your code, otherwise you will end up with a lot of errors.

Python 3 is stricter about separating the two types; if possible you should consider using it both for better unicode handling and because Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html